# An inequality about Hermitian matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-programming

Say one knows the following statement,

That for any Hermitian matrix $H$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 ..\geq \lambda_n$ one has, that in any basis, for any positive integers $1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq...\leq i_n \leq n$ and $k$ the inequality, $\lambda_{n-(k-1)} + \lambda_{n-(k-2)} + .. + \lambda_n \leq H_{i_1 i_2} + ... + H_{i_k i_k} \leq \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + .. + \lambda_k$

- Then from the above does it immediately follow that in any basis the diagonal n-tuple $(H_{11},H_{22},..,H_{nn})$ for any choice of basis lies in the convex hull of the $n!$ permutations of its eigenvalue n-tuple?

Comment: Do you really insist on "any choice of basis"? Shouldn't we just consider bases with unitarian transformation matrix? Otherwise, after transformation to an arbitrary basis, the diagonal elements $H_{jj}$ are not necessarily real, and the double inequality $\lambda_\cdots + \lambda_\cdots + \cdots \leq H_\cdots + H_\cdots + \cdots \leq \lambda_\cdots + \lambda_\cdots + \cdots$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jflipp Isn't what you are saying contradicting the Schur-Horn theorem? I thought that is the whole point of that to say that this sceanrio you describe is not possible - the diagonal n-tuple is always in the convex hull of the permutations of the eigenvalue n-tuples.

Comment: Maybe we should explicitly state what "in any basis" and "basis transformation mean. So let $H$ be the Hermitian matrix relative to a given basis, and let $T$ be the transformation matrix to a new basis. $T$ is not necessarily unitarian. Then how do we calculate $H$ relative to the new basis? Is it $THT^{-1}$? Or is it $THT^*$ (where $.^*$ means conjugation-transposition)? When I wrote my comment above, I was thinking about the transformation $THT^{-1}$.

Comment: Also, I skimmed through the notes of Terence Tao you cited below, and right before equation 9, he says "Specializing proposition 3 ...". Looking up proposition 3, we find that right before that, he's talking about subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb C^n$ and orthogonal bases of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the result you want follows from the argument you have. But you may want to take a look at the so-called Schur-Horn Theorem given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem). Let $H_{11},\dots,H_{nn}$ be in the decreasing order and $\lambda_i$'s in the order you have given. Define the vectors
\begin{align}
\mathbf{h}=\begin{bmatrix}H_{11} \\ \vdots \\ H_{nn}\end{bmatrix}~~,~~\mathbf{e}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then schur-horn theorem states that (there are different variations, more famous one is related to majorization) $$\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{e}$$ where $\mathbf{P}$ is a doubly stochastic matrix (rows and columns sums to one, and its entries are non-negative)
**This implies each diagonal entry of $\mathbf{H}$ is a convex combination of the eigenvalues.**

It is not so hard to prove this. Say $\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{U}\Lambda\mathbf{U}^H$ be its eigen value decomposition. See if you can express $\mathbf{h}=(\mathbf{U}\circ\mathbf{U})\mathbf{e}$ where $(\circ)$ is the hadamard product.

Comment: I am trying to understand how Terence Tao in his notes somehow thinks that polytope statement follows from this inequality I wrote - see around equation 9 in these notes.http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/

Comment: @dileep Isn't the assumption statement that I have written (which is equation 9) of the link above, a stronger statement than the majorization statement?

Comment: @user6818 doesn't the polytope statement easily follow from $h=Pe$? Have a look at the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem.

Comment: Well - the proof to that polytope lemma in your wiki link is not obvious to me - if that lemma is understood then my original question gets automatically answered.

Comment: and do you understand what jflipp is saying in the comment? - isn't Terence Tao's link's equation 9 not valid in every basis? Do I need a special basis to define the diagonal entries for the inequality to hold?

Comment: It would be great if you can help sort this out - also there was this related question that you could also help with - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033848/an-analytic-characterization-of-eigenvalues-of-a-hermitan-matrix

Comment: The proof for those statements can be surely found in the inequalities book of Marshall Olkin (I think it is there in Rajendra Bhatia's Matrix analysis as well). I don't understand the basis argument here. (All hermitian matrices are diagonalized by unitary matrices)

Comment: In inequality 9 of Terence Tao's notes that I had linked to, does he need a special basis to define his diagonal elements or will any basis do?